# How to use inner join with between sum and where

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Im trying to make a result page with 2 two tables

```
SELECT sum(dayfinal) AS dayfinal ,sum(undertimefinala) AS undertimefinala,sum(otfinal) AS otfinal,sum(day) AS day ,sum(ot) as ot , name ,empId ,position ,department ,rate ,pagibig ,sss
      FROM daily as daily INNER JOIN info as info

      WHERE daily.empId ='$number' and date BETWEEN cast('".$_POST["from_date"]."' as Date) 
      On daily.empId = info.empId
      AND cast('".$_POST["to_date"]."' as Date) 
      GROUP BY name
```

This is my query

I'm expecting an output like this

```
NAME | DAY | UNDERTIME| OVERTIME| OVERTIME HOURS | DEPARTMENT | Employee ID | SSS | PAGIBIG | 
Mark | 10  | 200      | 250     | 8              | GSO        | 8           | 360 | 200
```

Comment: Why would you expect only 9 columns in your results set when your `SELECT` is asking for 11 columns in a completely different order? I don't understand.

Also, when you use aggregate functions such as `SUM()`, you have to use `GROUP BY` on _all_ the non-aggregate columns in your `SELECT`. So you can't just use `GROUP BY name`, you must have also `empId ,position ,department ,rate ,pagibig ,sss`

Comment: You have your `where` and `on` clauses swapped out of order... it would be helpful to show the table structure with a few rows of data. I don’t know if *mysql* requires non-aggregate fields to be in the `group by` clause, but others certainly do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you havent specified the tables and its contents, i have modified your code , please map the table values correctly and give this a try. Or if you can share the table values then i can edit the answer.

```
SELECT sum(dayfinal) AS dayfinal ,
          sum(undertimefinala) AS undertimefinala,
          sum(otfinal) AS otfinal,
          sum(day) AS day ,
          sum(ot) as ot , 
          name , 
          empId ,
          position ,
          department ,
          rate ,
          pagibig ,
          sss
          FROM daily as daily INNER JOIN info as info
          On daily.empId = info.empId
          WHERE daily.empId ='$number' and date BETWEEN cast('".$_POST["from_date"]."' as Date)
          AND cast('".$_POST["to_date"]."' as Date) 
          GROUP BY name
```

Comment: Glad to hear that!! Please accept this as the solution if you feel it answers your question.

Answer (score 0):

Here's your query.After getting the `sum totals` of your `empId`, you can join the `info` table, to get the employee details.

```
SELECT t1.dayfinal
        ,t1.undertimefinala
        ,t1.otfinal
        ,t1.day
        ,t1.ot,
        ,i.name 
        ,i.empId 
        ,i.position 
        ,i.department 
        ,i.rate 
        ,i.pagibig 
        ,i.sss FROM (
    SELECT sum(dayfinal) AS dayfinal 
        ,sum(undertimefinala) AS undertimefinala
        ,sum(otfinal) AS otfinal
        ,sum(day) AS day 
        ,sum(ot) as ot 
        ,empId
    FROM daily as daily 
    WHERE empId ='$number' and date BETWEEN cast('".$_POST["from_date"]."' as Date)     
    AND cast('".$_POST["to_date"]."' as Date) 
    GROUP BY empId) as t1
LEFT JOIN info i on t1.empId = i.empId
```